# Positioning of text in CSS when minimizing the screen

Tags: html, css

I assigned a division in the webpage and when I minimize the browser the division does not adjust properly to the screen:

```
width:1300px;
margin:0 auto;
height:40px;
```

Comment: Could you paste the rest of the code? (CSS and HTML)

Comment: it's a long code...please specify what would you like to look at so i can then attach it here

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage(%) to set the width and height properties or use media query for responsive design.
[Learn more about responsive web design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)